# check if an image exists + loading an image without knowing the whole name of it

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

- how can I check if an image exist via javascript.
- is it possible to load an image called `145_44.jpg` and I only know the first 3 numbers `145`?

Comment: Where would this image be located? Is it an already existing element on the page?

Comment: For security reasons, it's not possible for javascript (in standard configuration) to browse folders and files in disk, if is this what you wanna do.

Comment: no its not an existing element. I have to create `<img />`

Comment: @SLaks m just saying :P if possible

Comment: Your questions are extremely unclear.

Comment: @rcdmk I understand that. however, u can load images using javascript!!. I just wanna know if the image does not exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html image element has onerror and onload events that will fire if loading the image fails or succeeds respectively.

With regards to loading an image without knowing the correct URI, the answer is no. Its up to the web server to decide what to serve in response to an HTTP request. If the request is for a resource it doesn't know about its very unlikely to serve anything other than a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you'll be able to link to an image without knowing the full name of it, however with the new CSS3 '*" selector you might be able to.

example:

```
    <img src="*145*.jpg" />
```

this might be able to catch it (i'm at work so i can't test) but give it a shot. the * replaces everything before/after it telling the browser to search for anything with the number 145 in it that is a .jpg